# Chromium not working with the mic of my logitech 270 webcam

Tags: chromium, webcam, microphone, google-hangouts

the mic on my Logitech 270 webcam has stopped working, but only on chromium. FFox is fine.
Is there anything I can do to debug it?

Btw I have tried changing the AV controls, alsa mixer, hangouts set up, etc.

When I open the hangouts setting it shows the mic, and it is selected. But the hangouts interface tells me that the mic is muted.

This does not happen when I start an hangout with FireFox. The mic used to work on Chromium, but I guess an update messed something up.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: and: Chromium Version 37.0.2062.94 Ubuntu 14.04 (290621) (64-bit)

Comment: just had a chromium update and still no joy. Any ideas?